# Force auto replace letters when typing inside order form

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Does anyone have an idea on how to auto replace letters in woocommerce order forms! basically I need when someone is typing in greeklish to auto replace those letters to Greek!

Comment: What if someone write in english in your order form. So `a` will become `α` for exemple ?

Comment: no worries there! the store does not ship orders to countries outside Greece! that's exactly what I need!

Comment: What is the final purpose here ? Because I don't think that it's ok to change text text that the user has sent.

Comment: When a user types in greeklish that creates a problem with the courier company that demands all characters to be Greek! the idea is when you type your name using greeklish it will simultaneously convert all letters to Greek before you finalize your order!

Answer (score 1):

I think you will have to use this hook to get the newly created order :

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'convert_greeklish_for_wc_order',  1, 1  );
function create_invoice_for_wc_order() {
   function create_invoice_for_wc_order( $order_id ) { 
    // get order details data...
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    // Here goes the code to get all the fields

    // Convert fields to greek

    // Set new fields values
   }; 
}
```

And adapt this code to convert greeklisk to greek:

```
<?php

function greeklish($new_text){

        $greek_len   = array('α','ά','Ά','Α','β','Β','γ', 'Γ', 'δ','Δ','ε','έ','Ε','Έ','ζ','Ζ','η','ή','Η','θ','Θ','ι','ί','ϊ','ΐ','Ι','Ί', 'κ','Κ','λ','Λ','μ','Μ','ν','Ν','ξ','Ξ','ο','ό','Ο','Ό','π','Π','ρ','Ρ','σ','ς', 'Σ','τ','Τ','υ','ύ','Υ','Ύ','φ','Φ','χ','Χ','ψ','Ψ','ω','ώ','Ω','Ώ',' ',"'","'",',');

        $english_len = array('a', 'a','A','A','b','B','g','G','d','D','e','e','E','E','z','Z','i','i','I','th','Th', 'i','i','i','i','I','I','k','K','l','L','m','M','n','N','x','X','o','o','O','O','p','P' ,'r','R','s','s','S','t','T','u','u','Y','Y','f','F','ch','Ch','ps','Ps','o','o','O','O',' ','',' ',' ');
        $new_text  = str_replace($greek_len,$english_len,$new_text);
        return $new_text;
    }

    $conv = greeklish("Το κείμενο σου εδώ!");

    echo $conv; #To keimeno sou edo!

?>
```